# 32 or 64 bit OS for 2GB RAM on a VPS?

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, vps

I'm going to be running only a dedicated game server on the VPS so performance is everything. I normally would go with 64-bit but since I only have 2 gigs of RAM should I stick with 32-bit? I hear about 32-bit being faster with less RAM, but 64-bit being better with stuff like video encoding which I would not be doing. People still swear by 64-bit OS's, so I'm having second thoughts.

So, should I go with 32-bit or 64-bit? Is 32-bit really that much more efficient?

EDIT: By efficient, I mean performance-wise. Will it be that much faster on 32-bit?

EDIT2: I will be using an SSD.

Comment: Please define "efficient".

Comment: Picking an "ssd" to a "hdd" is probably more important for performance. 32 or 64 bit is impossible to answer... it depends on usage.

Comment: Ah, I'm using an SSD that's for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

64 bit should more compute per cycle because of the wider registers and you have more registers to play with. I've run several compute bound benchmarks (for example lmbench) and compared 32 bit vs 64 bit in terms of throughput and throughput per watt and 64 bit wins in many scenarios.

Architecturally, 64 bit just allows the compiler to keep more data in registers since 64 bit has more and they are wider. More registers probably allows better internal CPU instruction re-ordering and pipelining and hence more throughput.

The downside is that addressing is larger meaning larger executables, so you may see a minor impact in extra instruction cache misses.  But really, go for 64 bit is my advice.

For reference, here are some benchmarks I did on a X220 a while back comparing pure 32 bit, 32 bit user space + 64 bit kernel, 64 bit userspace + 64 bit kernel and x32.  http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/x32/Raring-benchmarks/power-consumption/x32-power-analysis.txt

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware arch is 64bit, I would go with 64bit guest OS. This will allow the guest of taking advantage of the 64bit arch where it can - [source](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001498.htm).

There could come a time where you would like to migrate the guest to a host with more ram. Staying with 64bit OS, will allow that to be an easier migration.

You have mentioned that you are looking for speed. You are running a guest on a host. Why not install both the 32 and 64 version and test them both out under a load. This is will give you more of a real world experience.

Some apps that are 32bit do not run well on 64bit arch, regardless if the OS is 32bit or not.